# SystemD timer error on CentOS7 : Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: Mon..Sat *-*-* 18:00:00

Tags: bash, centos, systemd, centos-7, timer

My timer is rejected by the system on CentOS7 :

```
$ journalctl -u synchro_ADN_To_Scality.timer --no-pager | sed 's/^.*systemd.1.: //' | sort -u
-- Logs begin at Thu 2023-04-06 10:25:28 CEST, end at Thu 2023-05-25 12:29:08 CEST. --
synchro_ADN_To_Scality.timer lacks value setting. Refusing.
[/usr/local/lib/systemd/system/synchro_ADN_To_Scality.timer:4] Failed to parse calendar specification, ignoring: Mon..Sat *-*-* 18:00:00
$ systemctl cat synchro_ADN_To_Scality.timer
# /usr/local/lib/systemd/system/synchro_ADN_To_Scality.timer
[Unit]
Description=Lancement quotidien de la Synchro des Synology ADN vers le Ring Scality
[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon..Sat *-*-* 18:00:00
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

I see no date ranges in the `systemd.time` manual :

```
$ man systemd.time | grep -F ".."
$
```

Are date ranges not recognised on CentOS7 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature [was added](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/main/NEWS) in systemd version 231:

```
CHANGES WITH 231:

        * Calendar time specifications in .timer units now understand a ".."
          syntax for time ranges. Example: "4..7:10" may now be used for
          defining a timer that is triggered at 4:10am, 5:10am, 6:10am and
          7:10am every day.

        — Berlin, 2016-07-25
```

Comment: Thanks, on my side, I found intervals were used with a `-` character : `man systemd.time | grep -1 range`

Comment: I didn't realize that's a possibility. (We use `-` for YYYY-MM-DD dates, so the same would never have worked for day ranges.)